# Disable click and drag cut and paste in IntelliJ Idea IDE

Tags: intellij-idea, drag-and-drop, editor, settings

In my IntelliJ Idea 13.1.2 IDE I keep running into situations where I'm selecting on a click and drag via my laptop touch pad. I keep accidentally clicking and dragging text and cutting lines. I've searched the options and settings panels for the words click and drag but I don't see a way to turn this feature off. IntelliJ's help talks about how to use click and drag cutting but doesn't say how to disable it.
Does anyone know how to disable cut and paste through click and drag in the IntelliJ IDE?

Comment: Very annoying feature for me too.

Comment: @gumkins Yeah, wow was that an annoying feature for so many years.

Comment: IntelliJ editor has 10,000 features I love and use and forget everyday. This is one of the 10 I hate and remember. #CodeParkourFeatures

Comment: Confirmed, dumb feature.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

I found it in *Settings* → *Editor* → *General*.

Under the **Mouse** heading. The option is called "Enable Drag'n'Drop functionality in editor".

This also seems to disable drag and drop moving of files though.

Comment: While that option will prevent text drag&drop, it does not disable DnD in the file list. :(

Comment: Yup, that's right, it doesn't change the file list. The issue I was having was just with text so that fixed it. Are you trying to disable file drag and drop as well?

Comment: Yeah, I often get the move confirmation dialog when I meant to click a file or dir.

Comment: File list drag-n-drop can be disabled by going to Appearance & Behavior - Appearance, check "Drag-n-drop with ALT pressed only". Or just search by 'drag' word.

Comment: Great! I think the Intellij change something recently, it became very easy to drag, disable it resolve the problem

Comment: I actually love the feature of dragging selected text. But I can live without it because I hate even more the unintentional dragging of a **highlighted searched-for term**. It took a long time to realize what was happening, that when I was trying to swipe-select a _portion_ of a highlighted phrase, it was selecting and dragging the _whole_ phrase instead. Wish I could just disable _that_.

Comment: Thank, you're a life saver. In my case, a hair saver, as that's less hair ripping I do while trying to select text and the basterd keeps dragging text, something I will never use.

Answer (score 13):

In WebStorm 2020.1 (and presumably in other Jetbrains IDEs), the related option '*Move code fragments with drag-and-drop*' is in *Preferences* > *Editor* > *General*:

[image]

Unchecking the checkbox does the trick without unwanted side effects such as also disabling the drag-and-drop operations for files etc.

Comment: it does not disable drag'n'drop in project area. PS. Appearance & Behavior - Appearance, check "Drag-n-drop with ALT pressed only"

Comment: @SimonLogic The OP's question does not pertain the dragging and dropping files and folders in the Project pane. It is about cutting and pasting of the code in the editor via drag and drop.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to disable Drag-n-drop highlighted text in the editor itself!!! ALT guard for drag-n-drop files is a good idea as I accidentally drag and drop files on daily basis. Kudos for discovering that I just enabled it.

I have contacted Intellij support to give us a setting that we can disable in editor drag and drop. I think that is a stupid feature in the first place...