# How to disable the drag and drop move dialog in PyCharm?

Tags: intellij-idea, drag-and-drop, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

Drag and drop is easy to get used to and work with (for the more physical/muscle-memory spirits like me), considered annoying by others, no problem... but when each time a dialog comes up, it's super annoying!!

I found out how to disable the drag and drop feature here: [Disable click and drag cut and paste in IntelliJ Idea IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23370078/disable-click-and-drag-cut-and-paste-in-intellij-idea-ide)

But I would use it for shifting a few files quickly from one folder to another, not waste time leaving the IDE or thinking about questions like this.

Please help!

Comment: Not sure what exactly your question is. Do you want the files to be moved without showing the dialog? That's not possible.

Comment: I don't understand a question neither. What do you want to do with lines, move them where quickly ?

Comment: @yole, I wanted to move files without showing the dialog, yes.